# how to push data to chartjs dataset

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

i try to create a chart with chartnew.js but i failed to load my second data from array, this is my java script

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var newopts = {
        legend: true,
        inGraphDataShow: false,    
    }

    var cobaisiprice = [];
    var cobaisiqty = [];
    var cobaisitoko = [];

    @foreach (var label in Model)
                {
                    <text>
    cobaisiprice.push('@label.Total_Price');
    cobaisiqty.push('@label.Total_Qty');
    cobaisitoko.push('@label.Store');
    </text>
                }

    var data = {
        labels: cobaisitoko,
        datasets: [
         {
             title: "Price",
             fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
             strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
             pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
             pointstrokeColor: "yellow",
             data: cobaisiprice,
         },
          {
              title: "Qty",
              fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
              strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
              pointColor: "green",
              pointstrokeColor: "yellow",
              data: cobaisiqty,
          }
        ]
    };

    window.onload = function () {
        var myStackedBar = new Chart(document.getElementById("barPrice").getContext("2d")).Bar(data, newopts);
    }
</script>
```

[image]

please help me, why my second data ( cobaisiqty ) is not to show anything in chartnewjs, it's only show data from cobaisiprice, when i test with array data like [10,20,30,40,50] it's work, thanks for help